# Can I write all the functions that need to be called only one time as IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

from (Seems this is not allowed as per http://es5.github.io/#x12.4)

```
    function a () {};
    a();
```

or

```
    var a = function () {};
    a();
```

to

```
    (function () {}) ();
```

if a() will be called only once?  It looks conciser.

---

OK I will post my codes:

```
    const qty = []; 
    ((...setAmt) => {
        for (let i of setAmt) {
            qty.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)))
        }
    }) (10, 20, 10, 5, 20, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20);
```

vs

```
    const qty = [];
    const generator = (...setAmt) => {
        for (let i of setAmt) {
            qty.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)))
        }
    };
    generator(10, 20, 10, 5, 20, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20);
```

This is to generate a series of random integers between 0 and i.

I also have some other functions in similar situations that only execute once.

Comment: it really depends on your actual code - can you write it as an IIFE? well, can *you* write the code as an IIFE - we don't know the code. Is an IIFE the correct "tool" to use? We dont' know, it's your code ...

Comment: Can you? Of course. Should you? Almost certainly not: it adds an unnecessary layer of obfuscation, is impossible to test, and is pointless. Side note: this looks "more concise" because it's a function that doesn't do anything; most functions actually have code in them, making it more difficult to see it's an IIFE.

Comment: consider that the "concise" aspect is not the only thing that changes between the `let a = f(){}; a();` and `(()=>{})()`

Comment: Yeah but coming to es6+ we don't need it for variable isolation IMO

Comment: I use IIFE when I need to preserve inside vars or functions, generally for big piece of code. jQuery Library is build on IIFE

Comment: If you value concise code, I would think a simple `array.map()` would be better than either of your above options.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## You can, but you shouldn't

iifes can be faster to write, but a ton slower to read, cause you have to read the whole function to figure out what it does. It can be a nightmare when bugs start to show up.

### Code have to be readable & maintanable, imagine you have to read someones code that have hundreds of lines, what would you like to see named functions or iifes all over the place?

Also a better aproach below :

```
    const generateYourPhoneBill = (...args) => [...args].map((v) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (v + 1)));

    const lastMonth = generateYourPhoneBill(10, 20, 10, 5, 20, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20);
```